# Crontab can only schedule for every minutes

Tags: linux, cron, schedule

So i want to try make a basic schedule with crontab, this is the basic script :

```
* * * * * date >> /home/clauds/crontab.log
* * * * * cp /home/clauds/ahmadbagas /home/clauds/bckup
* * * * * cp /home/clauds/masjayeng.txt /home/clauds/bckup
```

if i do it like that it works, but when i try to change to backup file for every 5 minutes or else it doesn't work:

```
5 * * * * date >> /home/clauds/crontab.log
2 * * * * cp /home/clauds/ahmadbagas /home/clauds/bckup
5 * * * * cp /home/clauds/masjayeng.txt /home/clauds/bckup
```

i try to add user in the command like this :

```
5 * * * * root date >> /home/clauds/crontab.log
2 * * * * root cp /home/clauds/ahmadbagas /home/clauds/bckup
5 * * * * root cp /home/clauds/masjayeng.txt /home/clauds/bckup
```

it's still doesn't work, and give a error message like this:

> /bin/sh: root: command not found

can someone help me, why am i only can make schedule for everyminutes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
*/5 * * * * date >> /home/clauds/crontab.log
*/2 * * * * cp /home/clauds/ahmadbagas /home/clauds/bckup
*/5 * * * * cp /home/clauds/masjayeng.txt /home/clauds/bckup
```

The second one will be every two minutes

Comment: @Claud, any feedback ?